# More helpful stack traces on server error with Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When a server error occurs on Next.js, the call stack gives me the component where the error occurred but it does not give anything help beyond that.

For example, in `pages/index.js` I include a component called `Test`. This component includes another component called `Test2`, where the error occurs.

Next.js will tell me an error occurred in `Test2`, but does not mention `Test` or `pages/index.js`. So it's up to me to guess where `Test2` was included.

See here:

[image]

All the `/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/` calls are not helpful.

So how can I get a more helpful call stack when an error occurs in Next.js?

Comment: got any solution? kindly share!

Answer (score 0):

on the server side, I was able to print something like this (in typescript):

```
console.log((error as Error).stack);
```